# Is NSOpenPanel doesnot work in ios application

Tags: ios, dialog, modal-dialog

Hello.Am new to ios development.What have to do for NSOpenPanel to work in the ios application for opening the dialog box.Can somebody help me in doing so?Am really strucked with this NSOpenPanel.I made a lot of googling on this.If not what have to be used for opening a dialog box in ios applications.Can some body explain with me examples?And i also came to know that there are modal view controllers.Can please the example code of modal view controllers for opening a file dialog box in ios..Please....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS apps have no user-visible file system and thus, no NSOpenPanel.

Comment: Then how  to open the dialog box in ios

Comment: For file browsing? No such thing exists.

Comment: excuse me!IS there any alternative?

Comment: Exactly which files do you wish to browse?

Comment: is files are accessible in UIImageView